# Pycharm Intellisense for page class using pom framework with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Hey I'm trying to work this out but having a bit of trouble. Basically i'm trying to implement the Page Object Model framework with my selenium. I've created a page class where I pass my driver object to please see below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

class LoginPage:

   def __init__(self, driver):

       self.driver = driver

       self.email_field_xpath = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div/div[4]/div/form/div['
                                                                  '1]/input')

       self.password_field_xpath = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div/div['
                                                                     '4]/div/form/div[''2]/input')

       self.submit_button_xpath = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div/div[4]'
                                                                    '/div/form/button')

   def send_text_to_email_field(self):

       self.email_field_xpath.clear()
```

Although the code works when I run the main unit test, I can't seem to get the Intellisense to work in this class. I know the class doesn't know what the driver object is so it perhaps doesn't know what to suggest. Is there a way to let the class know the type of driver is to allow Intellisense to start working?

For example typing "self.driver.find" would suggest "find_element_by_id" ect.

Thanks